# Command to spawn in-game Player head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to spawn a player head in my custom Minecraft map I'm making, but the problem is, the username has to be defined to give the actual player's head:

```
/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"<playername>"}
```

But I want this to work for *any* player that plays the map. Is there a way to build a command to do this?

Comment: Not possible for any player, unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a random player's head?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360834/how-to-get-a-random-players-head) (mostly because that question has a less hacky answer that also answers this one)

Comment: @pppery my question is to give the skull of the player using the map, and therefore the command. That question is asking for just a random player head.

Comment: But it's the same technique. The answer to that question first selects a random player, and then creates their head. You would just substitute `@r` for `@p` in that answer and everything would work, hence IMO the questions are still duplicates.

Comment: @pppery But basing closure on answers is not good practice. This is asking for a command to select the current player, whereas the other question doesn't concern itself with that at all.

Comment: Both problem in both questions is the skull giving. Whether you use `@r` or `@s` to then apply that is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a script to do it...

This is written in Python and works on vanilla minecraft (even snapshots)

I currently give players a purple_shulker_box the first time they are seen by the server

https://github.com/Veritas83/Minecraft.SNAPSHOT.Commands.Mod/blob/master/commands.by.YT_Veritas0923.py

Line 1150-1153

```
if freeshulkerbox == True:
    cmdin = "give " + player + " purple_shulker_box 1\n"
    print "[" + get24hrtime() + "] [Script thread/EXEC]: " + cmdin,
    p.stdin.write(cmdin)
```

Change to:

```
if freeshulkerbox == True:
    cmdin = "give " + player + " minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:" + player + "}\n"
    print "[" + get24hrtime() + "] [Script thread/EXEC]: " + cmdin,
    p.stdin.write(cmdin)
```

I think this will accomplish what you are asking.

Update:

I just tested this, and it does indeed work. :)

[image]

Comment: Wow! Would thus work for a command block though? I want to do this for a single player map...

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no **known** way in minecraft to do this.