# How to get a random player's head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to give myself a random (@r) player's head on my server but I don't know if this is possible.

I'm on Minecraft 1.14.4 and when I place `minecraft:give @p player_head{SkullOwner:"@r"}` into a command block, it simply gives me the player head of "@r"

(I also found that without putting the quotation marks around the @r in the command, the command wouldn't be valid)

[image: give command in command block]

[image: player head of @r in hotbar]

Comment: usually, you can use the JSON text components to specify a selector like this: "{\"selector\":\"@p\"}". This concept can be used on signs, the /tellraw command and for a few more things but not for something like this. Is your server a Bukkit/Spigot server by any chance? because if so, you can use a plugin for that.

Comment: It's possible to do with loot tables, but a bit complicated. Good question! I'll figure it out later today and then answer if nobody does until then.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [loot table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Loot_table&oldid=1464379)) and the command [`/loot`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/loot) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/loot&oldid=1456032)) for this.

Firstly, the loot table that gives (or summons or inserts or whatever) the head of the player it is invoked on.
Minimal file structure of the datapack:

```
<datapack_name>
├pack.mcmeta
└data
 └head_loot
  └loot_tables
   └head.json
```

Here `head_loot` is an arbitrarily chosen namespace, which is reused in the command later. The same with `head.json`, only the file extension needs to be `.json`.

Contents of `pack.mcmeta` can vary depending on what you want, but this is a minimum example:

`{"pack":{"pack_format":3,"description":""}}`

Contents of `head.json`:

```
{
 "pools": [
  {
   "rolls": 1,
   "entries": [
    {
     "type":"minecraft:item",
     "name":"minecraft:player_head",
     "functions":
      [
       {
        "function":"fill_player_head",
        "entity":"this"
       }
      ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Now you can create heads of arbitrary (currently online) players. There are multiple ways to do this, the one that is actually intended for exactly this is:

```
/execute as @r run loot spawn ~ ~ ~ loot head_loot:head
```

This runs "as" a random player, but not "at" their position and summons a player head item entity at the execution position (a command block or whatever).

Make sure that the datapack is enabled, this command tells you that:

```
/datapack list
```

If you just changed something in the files, use `/reload`.