# How to get a player head using selector? (Java 1.19)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map and in this map I want to make cutscenes using armorstands. And I wonder - how to replace armorstand head slot with player head, that is placed according to selector (like @s). I know how to give  players head, but only by username (/give @s player_head{SkullOwner:"username"}), but if I try to use selector there (replace username with selector), it doesn't work - I just get Steve's head.

Comment: Doesn't work with only commands, you need `fill_player_head` in a [loot table](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Item_modifier#Item_function_JSON_format).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command to spawn in-game Player head?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307859/command-to-spawn-in-game-player-head)

Comment: However, that question is in dire need of a better answer, as the current one it has is a mess. [Fabian Röling's answer to the question I tried to close the target as a duplicate of](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/360854/185203) seems to be the most accurate and up to date, and I would suggest that @FabianRöling repost it on the question I linked.

Comment: Why should I duplicate it and not just close both as duplicate?

Comment: @FabianRöling The reason I said that was that the question had previously been reviewed as leave open by close vote queue for reasons explained in its comments. If you feel comfortable overriding that decision, then that works for me, given I tried to CV it myself two months ago.